# Load different template file when condition met?

Tags: filters, templates, hooks

If I visit a page on my WordPress site, WP goes and determines what template file it should use based on the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

If I'm doing some logic checking in the hook `init` and say my conditions are met, how do I tell WordPress to load a template file of my choosing, not the one WordPress would normally dish up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you perform the logic on the `template_include` filter? Else, you could set a global/constant and use that in `template_include` to serve up the appropriate template.

The template_include filter filers the path to the template file to be included. To avoid errors you should check if the template exists - locate_template does this for theme/child-theme files.

```
add_filter("template_include", "sc_redirect_properties_to_registration");
function sc_redirect_properties_to_registration( $template )
{
    if( is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page("the-properties") )
        return $template;

    //You could include templates from plugins
    //$template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'templates/plugin-template.php';

    //Best to check the template exists. With **theme/child-theme** templates
    // you can do this with locate_template.
    return locate_template('template-registration.php');
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of using this filter to change the choice of template file? The codex has a blank page on this filter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use some conditions like this:

```
if(is_front_page()){
    // Home page layout
} elseif(is_page()){
    // General page layout
    if(is_page('contact')){
        // Page layout specific to the contact page
    } elseif(is_page('about')){
        // Page layout specific to the about page
    }
}
```

Then obtain parts of your template depending on the section of your website using [`get_template_part();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: Sorry Michael I think you have misunderstood my question. I've edited my question to hopefully be a little more clearer to put across what I am after.