# How to set a fall back template for a custom post type in a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, templates

My custom plugin creates a custom post type, and I want to theme my own `"single-my_custom_cpt.php"` file. However, I want to store it in my plugin folder, and allow that it be over-written in the websites' active theme folder.

For example, single-my_custom_cpt.php exists in `/plugins/my-plugin/` folder, and someone creates `/themes/site-theme/single-my_custom_cpt.php`. I want the theme file to come up first, and if it's deleted, the plugin file to come up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Taxonomy in plugin and template](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50201/custom-taxonomy-in-plugin-and-template)

Comment: You might also find these questions helpful too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51038/template-include-overriding-default-plugin-templates-via-current-theme/51041#51041 http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55770/load-different-template-file-when-condition-met/55771#55771

Comment: @willbeeler Please use the edit buttons for code styling, etc. We appreciate that you will try to take the same effort asking questions and formatting them properly as we take when answering them. Thanks.

Comment: +1 on Stephen's links. Helped me quite a lot when I began working on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To provide a default template that can be overwritten by a theme hook into `template_include` like the linked questions suggest. You get the template WordPress wants to use as a parameter. If that is not the file you want – replace it with your plugin’s file:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_57232_render_cpt', 100 );

/**
 * Provide fall back template file for a custom post type single view.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_57232_render_cpt( $template )
{
    // Our custom post type.
    $post_type = 'my_custom_cpt';

    // WordPress has already found the correct template in the theme.
    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $template, "/single-$post_type.php" ) )
    {
        // return the template in theme  
        return $template;
    }

    // Send our plugin file.
    if ( is_singular() && $post_type === get_post_type( $GLOBALS['post'] ) )
    {
        // return plugin file
        return dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/single-$post_type.php";
    }

    // Not our post type single view.
    return $template;
}
```