# Change Post Template based on post meta?

Tags: page-template, post-meta

I am trying to figure out a way to use a custom template within my plugin.

I would like to avoid using a custom post type if possible. I searched for a way to add my theme file to the dropdown list in the admin (under page attributes), but nothing seems to work.

Here is what I have:

```
add_filter('page_template', 'catch_plugin_template');

function catch_plugin_template( $template ) {
if( is_page_template('page_template.php') ){
    $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myplugin/page_template.php';
    return $template;   
}
}
```

However, since I can never select "page_template.php" from the template list it wont fire. Any suggestions on how to fix this or another way to approach it? I have considered changing the template based on whether or not certain post meta has a value, but I can't get that to work.

The code above works fine if I remove the **if statement** but I'm hoping for some sort of viable alternative.

Comment: Please **search** the site (via Google) before asking. We've already had that question/answer. [Example here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/how-to-set-a-fall-back-template-for-a-custom-post-type-in-a-plugin), and another one [is here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it will work with if statement as well.

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

function catch_plugin_template( $template ) {

    if( is_page_template('page_template.php') ){

        $template = MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/page_template.php';

    } 

    return $template;   
} 
add_filter('template_include', 'catch_plugin_template');
```